# Python "if" statement not working

Tags: python

I was writing a complex program and I was getting an if statement...
(this isn't the complex code, this is just an example)

```
print("The 24 game will give you four digits between one and nine")   
print("It will then prompt you to enter an ewuation one digit at a time.")
import random
a = random.randint(1,9)
b = random.randint(1,9)
c = random.randint(1,9)
d = random.randint(1,9)
print(a,b,c,d)
f=input("Enter one of the above numbers")
if f==a:
    print("ok")
elif f != a:
    print("No")
```

No matter what I type it always outputs "NO".

Comment: Your code actually works fine for me

Comment: It will work on Python 2, but using `input` instead of `raw_input` with Python 2 is in 99,99% of all cases a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work after converting the user input string to a number:

```
if int(f) == a:
    print("ok")
```